# How to define the getter function of an array in javascript Object.defineProperty?

Tags: javascript

I expect that I can get the list by the `a.list`, but this code does not work except using original value return.

```
function myclass() {
  this._v = {
    list: []
  };
}

Object.defineProperty(myclass.prototype, 'list', {
  get: function() {
    // return this._v.list;
    return this._v.list.map(val => {
      console.log('val', val);
      return val;
    });
  }
});

var a = new myclass();
a.list.push('abc');
console.log(a.list);
```

Comment: Your getter returns a new array each time it's called. When you `push` to that array, this doesn't affect `_v.list` in any way.

Comment: what would you like to use to push an element?

Answer (score 1):

The getter is always returning a *new* empty array when called. When you push to it, there are no observable effects, because the array that's being changed isn't the array on the object.
You need to get a reference to the `_v.list` array so that you can push to it, which you can do either by reference it directly

```js
function myclass() {
  this._v = {
    list: []
  };
}

Object.defineProperty(myclass.prototype, 'list', {
  get: function() {
    return this._v.list.map(val => {
      return val;
    });
  }
});

var a = new myclass();
a._v.list.push('abc');
console.log(a.list);
```

Or add a different method that returns the `_v.list` array:

```js
function myclass() {
  this._v = {
    list: []
  }
}
myclass.prototype.getArr = function() {
  return this._v.list;
}

Object.defineProperty(myclass.prototype, 'list', {
  get: function() {
    return this._v.list.map(val => {
      return val;
    });
  }
});

var a = new myclass();
a.getArr().push('abc');
console.log(a.list);
```

Comment: `a.list.push('abc');` should be `a.list = 'abc';`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you wanted to push the elements in the `_v.list` and retrieve them from new `list` on `myclass`.

```js
function myclass() {
  this._v = {
    list: []
  };
}

Object.defineProperty(myclass.prototype, 'list', {
  get: function() {
    // return this._v.list;
    return this._v.list.map(val => {
      return val;
    })
  }
});

var a = new myclass();
a._v.list.push('abc');
console.log(a.list)
```

In your code you have overridden `get` method for `list` which is taking all its elements from `_v.list` but while pushing elements to `list` you are not pushing them to `_v.list`. That's why you are getting empty array which is `_v.list` not `list`.

Answer (score -1):

```
'use strict';
function myclass() {
  this._v = {
    list: []
  };
}

Object.defineProperty(myclass.prototype, 'list', {
  get: function() {
    // return this._v.list;
    console.log('list', this._v.list);
    return this._v.list.map(val => {
      return val;
    });
  },
  set: function(newVal) {
    this._v.list.push(newVal);
  }
});

const a = new myclass();
console.log(a);
a.list = 'abc';
console.log(a.list);
```